# Extracting city and state info out of zip codes in Excel

Tags: python, excel, powershell, scripting, zipcode

I need to extract city and state info out of the zip codes in my Excel sheet.
I have an Excel sheet which has over 50 thousands of zip codes in a single column, I created another 2 columns next to it as City and State.

Is there any easy way or any common formula to find out corresponding city and state names with these zip codes and populate them in city and state columns?

Thanks..

Comment: There is no formulaic calculation to derive a City and State from a zip code. You would need to use some database to get those mappings.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following python module ZipcodeSearchEngine:-

```
>>> from uszipcode import ZipcodeSearchEngine
>>> search = ZipcodeSearchEngine()
>>> zipcode = search.by_zipcode("10001")
>>> print(zipcode)
{
    "City": "New York",
    "Density": 34035.48387096774,
    "HouseOfUnits": 12476,
    "LandArea": 0.62,
    "Latitude": 40.75368539999999,
    "Longitude": -73.9991637,
    "NEBoundLatitude": 40.8282129,
    "NEBoundLongitude": -73.9321059,
    "Population": 21102,
    "SWBoundLatitude": 40.743451,
    "SWBoungLongitude": -74.00794499999998,
    "State": "NY",
    "TotalWages": 1031960117.0,
    "WaterArea": 0.0,
    "Wealthy": 48903.42702113544,
    "Zipcode": "10001",
    "ZipcodeType": "Standard"
}
```

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/uszipcode/#description for further readings.

Comment: He asked how to do this in PowerShell, not python... I would also argue that it is slightly easier to do this in PowerShell since *Excel* is a Microsoft product, as is PowerShell.

Comment: I agree Kolob about PoweShell use for accessing Excel. However, I found the python tag in question. So I thought it might be helpful for Hakan, although python is not that bad on window to process excel :)

Comment: ah, didn't see the Python tag my bad

Comment: You guys are awesome thanks a lot for your answers. I am totally a new to this platform so sorry if I asked my question in wrong way.

I also came up with an Excel formula:

=IF(A2="","",VLOOKUP(A2,'Zip Code Data'!A2:J42524,3))

it worked for almost half of my zip codes, it showed city and state names correctly but the other half it shows #NA for both city and state names.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure there is no algorithm to convert zip codes to City / State.

There is however a **database**: [federalgovernmentzipcodes.us](http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us/)

Click on "Free ZipCode Database" and it should download a `.csv` file to your downloads folder.

Then in PowerShell:

```
$all_zip_codes = Import-CSV "C:\path\to\database.csv"
$my_excel_sheet = Import-CSV "C:\path\to\my\file.csv"

function getCityAndState($zip_code)
{
      // loop through $all_zip_codes and find the data
}

$output_csv = "C:\path\to\my\output.csv"
$obj = new-object psobject
$arr = @()
foreach($my_row in $my_excel_sheet)
{
    $obj = $my_row;
    $cityState = getCityAndState($my_row.zipCode)
    $obj | Add-Member -Name 'City' -Value = $cityState.City
    $obj | Add-Member -Name 'State' -Value = $cityState.State
    $arr += $obj
    
}
$arr | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "$output_csv"
```

I stopped writing the code because you should be able to figure it out based on what I gave you. `Import-CSV` is going to be your friend here.